# How to manually add an error to a form component in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

I want to manually add an error to a form component.

I did this:

```
$form->get('videoId')->addError(new FormError('error message'));
```

But the error is getting assigned to the form itself, instead of the form component.
Do you have any idea why it is not assigned to my videoId field?

Thanks for your help

Comment: How are you displaying the errors?

Comment: Maybe you need to set 'error_bubbling' to false https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling

Comment: @Vyctorya it is false by default, but OP may have changed it, indeed

Comment: I'm displaying errors this way:
    {{ form_errors(form.videoId) }}

Comment: I've tried to set 'error_bubbling' to false but it changed nothing

Comment: I found my mistake... the field type is HiddenType, and it seems you can't assign errors to hidden fields for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake... the field type is HiddenType, and it seems you can't assign errors to hidden fields for some reason